# Merging of two JsonObject having same key and different value

Tags: java, json

I have two JsonObject having same key but different value.
I want to merge both JsonObject with same key in another JsonObject.

```
JSONObject a = new JSONObject("{\"data\": [ {\"empId\": 1,\"deptId\": 2},{\"empId\": 3,\"deptId\": 4}]}");
JSONObject b = new JSONObject("{\"data\": [ {\"empId\": 7,\"deptId\": 8},{\"empId\": 9,\"deptId\": 10}]}");
```

The result should be like this.

```
{\"data\": [ {\"empId\": 1,\"deptId\": 2},{\"empId\": 3,\"deptId\": 4},{\"empId\": 7,\"deptId\": 8},{\"empId\": 9,\"deptId\": 10}]}
```

Please Let me know how to do this.

Comment: What do you want the outcome to be?

Comment: It's not clear what you want as the result. Please provide object `c` which is the result of 'merging' of `a` and `b`.

Comment: I have edited the question, added the resultant JsonObject how it should be. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

Use `JSONArray` for store multiple `JSONObject`. Using this no need to worry to assign key for this `JSONObject` e.g.

```
JSONObject a = new JSONObject("{\"data\": [ {\"empId\": 1,\"deptId\": 2},{\"empId\": 3,\"deptId\": 4}]}");
JSONObject b = new JSONObject("{\"data\": [ {\"empId\": 7,\"deptId\": 8},{\"empId\": 9,\"deptId\": 10}]}");
```

**Edit**

```
JSONArray jArr_A= a.getJSONArray("data");

JSONArray jArr= new JSONArray();
for(int i=0;i<jArr_A.length();i++){
     jArr.put(jArr_A.getJSONObject(i));
}
```

Now for another object

```
jArr_A= b.getJSONArray("data");

for(int i=0;i<jArr_A.length();i++){
     jArr.put(jArr_A.getJSONObject(i));
}
```

now check the length of your jArr object has it double.

```
JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject();
mainJson.put("data", jArr);
```

Comment: please edit some one I am not able to getting code formatting tools

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i am getting JsonObjects from two different places having same key but values are list of different Objects. so i want to merge both list of Objects with same given key in new JsonObject.

Comment: this is working fine but there is issue if i don't have any key, like this ["{\"empId\": 1,\"deptId\": 2}"]. In that case it is not working. its throwing an Exception "data
org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]".